# Running NUnit tests on .net core project in MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, command-line, nunit

I've created a REST API using .net core and Visual Studio for Mac.

I could create an NUnit lib project to run my tests, and running them using Visual Studio is fine. The problem is that I cannot make the test run through the command line.

These are the NuGet packages I've installed:

[image: NuGet packages installed]

I've tryed the following commands:

- `$ dotnet test Solution.sln`
- `$ dotnet test Solution.Test/Solution.Test.csproj`

Both returns this:

```
$ dotnet test -v m
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
```

Is there any way to run the tests like this?

Also, I've noticed that my project is using the target framework `.NET Core 3.1` and the NUnit project is using `.NET Framework 4.7.2`. Is there any problem with this config?

My goal is to run the tests using Github Actions.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your test project targeting .NET 4.7.2? Or is the NUnit nuget package 4.7.2?

Comment: The NUnit project template in VS for Mac targets .NET Framework (aka Mono), so it won't work with .NET Core. Please use `dotnet new` https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-new-nunit

Comment: In the test project, it's targeting .NET 4.7.2. The NUnit package is 3.12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome! Thanks to Lex Li comment I solved the problem.

What I did to fix it was:

1. Deleted the test project;
2. Created a new project using: `$ dotnet new nunit --framework netcoreapp3.1 -n Solution.Name`

Now I have all the projects using the same .net core and I can run the tests in Visual Studio and in the Command-Line!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try cleaning the whole solution or all or the child projects and that may work.(It did for me)